# eigen3 missing error during ROS installation

Tags: ros, eigen3, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I'm trying to install ROS on my MAC suing homebrew.While installtion I got this message :

> ```
>  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package):
> ```

```
  By not providing "FindEigen3.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
 asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3", but
  CMake did not find one
 Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3" with any
 of the following names:
Eigen3Config.cmake
eigen3-config.cmake
 Add the installation prefix of "Eigen3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
 "Eigen3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Eigen3"
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
installed.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/Jishnu/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/pcl_ros/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
<== Failed to process package 'pcl_ros': 
 Command '['/Users/Jishnu/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh', 'cmake',      '/Users/Jishnu/ros_catkin_ws/src/perception_pcl/pcl_ros', '-  DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/Users/Jishnu/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/pcl_ros', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/Jishnu/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-G', 'Unix Makefiles']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I'M a beginner in ROS, so could someone please help me out with this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215408/eigen3-missing-error-during-ros-installation/) by [jishnu](https://answers.ros.org/users/23490/jishnu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-08-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jishnu](https://answers.ros.org/users/23490/jishnu/) on 2015-08-07**:
Hi I have eigen installed . The installed version is 3.2.4

**Comment by [dementor](https://answers.ros.org/users/21822/dementor/) on 2015-10-02**:
PCL Build on Mac seems to be broken. Try removing PCL packages and build it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have eigen3 installed? I'm not familiar with MAC/homebrew, but in ubuntu you can install it with `sudo apt-get install libeigen3-dev`.
According to [this](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/base.yaml#L556), it could be just `eigen3` for Mac.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2